# Opening a certain an excel file but only pulling one specified worksheet

Tags: excel

I currently have an excel file that has multiple worksheets and it takes very long to load. I only need one worksheet from it called "comparisons". May I ask how/if there's a way to open a specific worksheet and not load anything else. Hoping this will improve load time.

Comment: Are you referring to opening only specific `worksheet` from withing a `workbook` or you want to open a specific `workbook` from a particular folder containing other `excel workbooks`?

Comment: Sorry I meant worksheet! Let me fix that right away.

Comment: In that case you have no option but to open `workbook`, you cant just open a `worksheet` from within a `workbook`. Few options you can use is to set the manual calculation option in the `main workbook` so that the loading becomes faster.

Answer (score 0):

If your excel workbook have many sheets, you can compare worksheet name is "comparisons" then you open it. Otherwise don't open. You can use EPPLUS excel library to read excel sheet.

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
var sheetCount = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Count;
                    if (sheetCount > 0)
                    {
                        for (var y = 1; y <= sheetCount; y++)
                        {
                            if(pck.Workbook.Worksheets[y].Name=="comparisons")
                             {
                               // You open  sheet.
                             }
                            else
                             {
                             //Don't open sheet.
                             }
                        }
                    }
}
```